# boost version for node with external class

Tags: boost

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm using ros-electric on ubuntu 11.04, which brings boost1.42.
Since even the latest ros&ubuntu- combination features only boost1.46.1 I have the problem of getting a later boost version to work. It has to be >1.47 due to the geometry-packages.
Is there a safe way to get the whole ros to work with boost1.47 or even 1.49 ?
Another idea was, since this boost-version is just used in one single class, how to tell 'rosmake' in the cmakelist usse it just once. This is my attempt so far:

```
SET(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH ${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH} "/usr/local/boost_1_49_0")
SET(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} "/usr/local/boost_1_49_0/libs")
set(BOOST_ROOT /usr/local/boost_1_49_0)
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR /usr/local/boost_1_49_0)
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR /usr/local/boost_1_49_0/libs)
    set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS   ON)
    set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
    find_package(Boost 1.49.0 COMPONENTS geometry )

   if(Boost_FOUND)
      include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
   endif()
rosbuild_add_executable(shutter src/shutter.cpp src/geometry.cpp)
target_link_libraries(src/geometry.cpp ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Might be a few to many 'set's, but it got the class compiled before(using 'cmake' without the 'rosbuild...'-commands).

rosmake gives me:

```
fatal error: boost/geometry.hpp: file not found
```

This at the point, where geometry.hpp is included in my source.
Any way I can use my external class in my ros node ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33966/boost-version-for-node-with-external-class/) by [g17](https://answers.ros.org/users/2377/g17/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-05-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, how I solved it:
I put the class with the higher boost requirements into a static library, leading cmake to use the boost version I wanted with the code above. Then compiled it.
I referred to this library in the rest of the code, which I could then compile with 'rosmake'.
Note:
I had to delete any trace to boost in the library-header file. Also I did not see this solution first, since Im quite new to C++. The static library might get quite big, when not only the geometry-part of boost is included.

---

Originally posted by [g17](https://answers.ros.org/users/2377/g17/) with karma: 26 on 2012-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moataz Elmasry](https://answers.ros.org/users/116/moataz-elmasry/) on 2012-09-05**:
This sounds dangerous and unstable. I'd try to really solve the problem and not just patch it. this code might also be not portable

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That sounds tricky.

I recommend installing the latest ROS and Ubuntu distributions: Fuerte on Ubuntu Precise (12.04). Some (not all) of those boost packages are at version 1.48. You should probably check the versions of the exact packages you require on the Ubuntu site, first.

That seems like the safest solution, unless Electric on Natty is a requirement for other reasons.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-05-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1